# How to display unpublished contents in views for all the users?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, workbench

I need to display published as well as unpublished content for all the authenticated users. Also, site also has workbench moderation module enabled.

I have tried by pass access control permission, view unpublished contrib module.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Add Permission - Workbench Moderation : View all unpublished content.

Answer (score 0):

In your view's settings under Other, click Query settings and check Disable SQL rewriting.

This disables node access checks so be sure to set up the view carefully.